# jmeter how to record http(s) script recorder for uploading xml file

Tags: python-3.x, performance, file-upload, jmeter

jmeter 5.0 windows 10

I am using jmeter to load test a localhost:5000 app and want to record it using htts test script recorder 
I go file-->templates-->select template --create and it scaffolds a test for me 
I then go to firefox and go to proxy and change setting and also install the certificate

I then click on the http(s) test script recorder on the left and hit the start button which results in a pop up to install the certificate

then there is another pop up  [image]

what values should i be selecting in html sampler setting and the highlighted

this is what I want to achieve

go to http://localhost:5000/
then upload a xml file(I have stored it in my jmeter/bin dir) and get a multi checkbox item  results back 
then check some of the check boxes and then hit submit button

Answer (score 0):

1. `Prefix` - is just a string which will be added to the generated [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler labels. If you don't provide any prefix you will have the names like `1, 2, 3, 4, etc.`:

   [image]

   If you set something as the prefix - it will be added to each sampler name

   [image]
2. `Create new transaction after request (ms)` - if you put i.e. `5000` into this field and during recording you will not click anywhere for 5+ seconds - JMeter will put all subsequent requests into a new [Transaction Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-transaction-controller). Transaction Controller's main function is to measure the total child of its children. for example on the above image `foo10` is the Transaction Controller and it will measure the cumulative time of execution of samplers from `foo10` to `foo17` and report it as a single transaction. For example you can have your whole sequence as a single transaction or have 2 separate transactions: upload file and submit.
3. Just in case make sure your [Firefox proxy settings look](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/connection-settings-firefox) like:

   [image]

   to wit:

   - proxy is being used for all protocols
   - no exclusions are being made
4. You should be importing certificate into the Firefox **after** starting the proxy as the certificate has limited life time span (7 days) and if you will not be recording for more than 7 days you will not be able to use the certificate anymore without regenerating it. So make sure that "fresh" certificate is imported into the Firefox.

Comment: After struggling with Jmeter for half a day, some one else recommended badboy software and its very simple to use and to top it you can export from badboy to jmeter , and I do not work for Badboy software and not connected to it in any way

Comment: Thank you Dmitri T for providing solution. I am also facing same issue and I did not see this window in previous Jmeter versions. after entering these values as well, the pop up is not going away. Is there a way to disable this pop up and work normally as other Jmeter version?